# ERROR:flask_oidc:ERROR: Unable to get token info

Tags: python, flask, keycloak

I am trying to setup keycloack integration with a simple flask api. I am trying to use https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/145dc9aa857b831ff2eff221b79d179a as the reference for setting up simple api. I have seen similar questions on this issue on stack overflow, but I didnt get any solution through these questions. May be some one can help me resolve this issue.

My code:

`app.py`

```
import json
import logging

from flask import Flask, g
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect
import requests

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update({
    'SECRET_KEY': 'SomethingNotEntirelySecret',
    'TESTING': True,
    'DEBUG': True,
    'OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS': 'client_secrets.json',
    'OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE': False,
    'OIDC_REQUIRE_VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
    'OIDC_USER_INFO_ENABLED': True,
    'OIDC_OPENID_REALM': 'apiv3-login',
    'OIDC_SCOPES': ['openid', 'email', 'profile'],
    'OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD': 'client_secret_post',
    'OIDC_TOKEN_TYPE_HINT': 'access_token'
})

oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    if oidc.user_loggedin:
        return ('Hello, %s, <a href="/private">See private</a> '
                '<a href="/logout">Log out</a>') % \
               oidc.user_getfield('preferred_username')
    else:
        return 'Welcome anonymous, <a href="/private">Log in</a>'


@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
@oidc.accept_token(require_token=True)
def hello_api():
    """OAuth 2.0 protected API endpoint accessible via AccessToken"""
    return json.dumps({'hello': 'Welcome %s' % g.oidc_token_info['sub']})

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    """Performs local logout by removing the session cookie."""
    oidc.logout()
    return 'Hi, you have been logged out! <a href="/">Return</a>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

`client_secrets.json`

```
{
    "web": {
        "issuer": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/apiv3",
        "auth_uri": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/apiv3/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
        "client_id": "apiv3-login",
        "client_secret": "5551fe75-38c5-435a-a392-a6da6252439e",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "http://localhost:5000/*"
        ],
        "userinfo_uri": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/apiv3/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
        "token_uri": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/apiv3/protocol/openid-connect/token",
        "token_introspection_uri": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/apiv3/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the token using the endpoint(using postman)

http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/apiv3/protocol/openid-connect/token

with grant type: password.

With the access token I am trying to call localhost:5000/api with authorization header bearer access token from above step. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The flask error shows `ERROR:flask_oidc:ERROR: Unable to get token info`